# Select count strings then group them to pie chart

Tags: php, mysql, amcharts

I really need to finish this, I need them to be grouped by four, Im currently using pie chart for my table to show the percentage of each items, and their count using this query:

> This is my full code: https://www.pastiebin.com/5be43c1f6ec73

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT trendx, COUNT(*) as counter FROM jeremy_table_trend GROUP BY trendx";
```

Then this is the result of my query

```
Escalate                        99
Not Supported                12809
PE.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026       23
PE.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027      102
PUA.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026       1
PUA.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027      16
PUA.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027P0005  1
Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF026   96
Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027  619
Rapid Proliferation            596
TROJ.Win32.TRX.XX.PE50FFF026     5
Undet                         1425
Undet - component               17
Undet - Feedback               712
Undet - FileSize                 9
Undet - M/P                     73
Undet - Maturity               146
```

This is the output of my piechart, but I want them to be group by 4 - `Undetected, Supported,Escalate and Not Supported`. How can I do this? Please help me

[image]

This is my chart code:

```
<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "fontSize":15,
  "type": "pie",
  "startDuration": 0,
   "theme": "black",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend":{
    "fontSize":15,
    "position":"right",
    "marginRight":250,
    "autoMargins":false
  },
  "innerRadius": "0",
  "defs": {
    "filter": [{
      "id": "shadow",
      "width": "200%",
      "height": "200%",
      "feOffset": {
        "result": "offOut",
        "in": "SourceAlpha",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0
      },
      "feGaussianBlur": {
        "result": "blurOut",
        "in": "offOut",
        "stdDeviation": 5
      },
      "feBlend": {
        "in": "SourceGraphic",
        "in2": "blurOut",
        "mode": "normal"
      }
    }]
  },
  "dataProvider": 
  [
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>

    {
      "TRENDX": "<?php echo $row['trendx'] ?>",
      "Values": <?php echo $row['counter']; ?>
    },

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  ]
  ,
  "valueField": "Values",
  "titleField": "TRENDX", 
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:20px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "angle": 20,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

chart.addListener("init", handleInit);

chart.addListener("rollOverSlice", function(e) {
  handleRollOver(e);
});

function handleInit(){
  chart.legend.addListener("rollOverItem", handleRollOver);
}

function handleRollOver(e){
  var wedge = e.dataItem.wedge.node;
  wedge.parentNode.appendChild(wedge);
}
</script>
```

I'm thinking of this idea but I dont know how to group them by four

**For undet:**

```
select trendx, COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Undet%';
```

**For Escalate:**

```
select trendx, COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Escalate%';
```

**For Not Supported:**

```
select trendx, COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Not Supported%';
```

**For Supported:**

```
select trendx, COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx NOT LIKE '%Not Supported%' OR '%Undet%' OR '%Escalate%';
```

Comment: It might be useful to provide the data set too.

Comment: I posted my full code, please help me to answer this

Comment: Which is why I suggested that you might also provide the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this, you could use a union query

```
select 'Undet' as trendx, COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Undet%'
union all
select 'Escalate', COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Escalate%'
union all
select 'Not Supported', COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx LIKE '%Not Supported%'
union all
select 'Supported', COUNT(*) as counter from jeremy_table_trend WHERE trendx NOT LIKE '%Not Supported%' OR '%Undet%' OR '%Escalate%';
```

or alternatively you could use a case statement and subquery, something like

```
select status, count(*) from ( 
  select 
   case 
    when trendx like '%Undet%' then 'Undet'
    when trendx like '%Escalate%' then 'Escalate'
    when trendx LIKE '%Not Supported%' then 'Not Supported'
    else 'Supported'
   end as status
) x group by status
```